# Look-ahead and look-behind assertions with regexprep

Tags: regex, matlab

The following works as expected with `perl`'s `s///g` string replacement operator:

```
  DB<18> $s = 'camelCaseText.ext'
  DB<19> $s =~ s/\W|(?<=[^\WA-Z_])(?=[A-Z])/\$/g; print $s
camel$Case$Text$ext
```

...but fails almost completely in MATLAB:

```
>> regexprep('camelCaseText.ext', '\W|(?<=[^\WA-Z_])(?=[A-Z])', '$')

ans =

camelCaseText$ext
```

How can one achieve the effect illustrated by the `perl` example using MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify the `emptymatch` option.  According to [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html), it ignores zero-length matches by default.

```
>> regexprep('camelCaseText.ext', '\W|(?<=[^\WA-Z_])(?=[A-Z])', '$', 'emptymatch')
```

Comment: Did not know that!  I was trying to make the code more readable, but that kinda defeats the purpose.  I'll just condense it to one line.  Thanks for the heads-up.